# Facebook Thumbnail picture when link is shared will not update

Tags: facebook, meta-tags

I recently changed the logo of my website along with the title of the site. For the logo, I kept the same file name, logo.jpg, just deleted the old picture and replaced it with the new picture. For some reason, when a link is shared via Facebook, the old logo still shows up as the thumbnail picture.

For the title, It appears to work when a link is shared, but when two people share the same link and Facebook recognizes it and states, "Friend 1 and Friend 2 have both shared the link ***_*__**." the old title appears.

I changed the meta tag:

meta property="og:title" content="Title ABC"

yet it still has not updated. Do Facebook updates take a little time to process, does Facebook cache the image or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with LinkedIn. I added `<meta property="og:image" content="https:` and so on to my index.html, but LinkedIn kept pulling the wrong picture because it had already cached my site.

Here's the trick to force the embedding app (LinkedIn, Facebook, etc.) to treat your website as never cached before and therefore read it completely from scratch, including your new `og:image`.

When you input your full link to the social media site, add `?01` at the very end of it. E.g. `https://example.com?01` or `https://example.com/my_project/?01`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the URL through the [Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to clear the cache? This tool will also help you resolve any mistakes you've made with your tags.

Note that you can't change the title after 50 people have liked it, so be aware of that

Comment: I did run the URL through the debugger and it appears to work there, but when I share a link, it still appears as the old one.

Comment: And it has less than 50 likes? that could be a bug

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem and was researching it when a senior Dev on my team (I'm a Junior) told me to use the debug tool to clear the cache and to make sure that I clear it with http://YOURSITE.HERE/WITHSLASH/ and http://YOURSITE.HERE/WITHOUTSLASH and it worked by taking the slash off of the end for me.

Comment: Welp, looks like this is a dead thread anyway, 2012. But if anyone else encounters this hopefully it will help them.